# Codeigniter Template library, add_js() method

Tags: codeigniter, templates

using [This Template Library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html)

When I try and use the `add_js()` function it errors out.  I add the regions `$_scripts` to the template header file but when I load the page it says undefined variable `_scripts`.

any thoughts?

changed `<?= $_scripts ?> to <?= (isset($_scripts)) ? $_scripts : “”; ?>`

and obviously I lose the error but the js file still isn't loading.

I did an echo at each step though the `add_js()` method and the output is correct.  I also did an output of `$this->js` and they both had the correct output.  So it gets through the `get_js` method fine and sets the class variable fine but I don't get anything added to the actual page.

Answer (score 0):

sorry different computer now.

here is the controller method:

```
function registrationForm(){
    $this->template->set_template('single');
    $this->template->write_view('header', 'templates/header_template');
    $this->template->write_view('footer', 'templates/footer_template');
    $this->template->write_view('center', 'user/registration_form');
    $this->template->add_js('js/jquery.min.js');
    $this->template->add_js('js/validate.jquery.js');
    $this->template->render();
}
```

here is the head section:

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="<?= base_url() ?>css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<?= (isset($_scripts)) ? $_scripts : ""; ?>
<?= (isset($_styles)) ? $_styles : ""; ?>
</head>
```

and the add_js() method:

```
function add_js($script, $type = 'import', $defer = FALSE)
   {
      $success = TRUE;
      $js = NULL;

      $this->CI->load->helper('url');

      switch ($type)
      {
         case 'import':
            $filepath = base_url() . $script;
            $js = '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. $filepath .'"';
            if ($defer)
            {
               $js .= ' defer="defer"';
            }
            $js .= "></script>";
            break;

         case 'embed':
            $js = '<script type="text/javascript"';
            if ($defer)
            {
               $js .= ' defer="defer"';
            }
            $js .= ">";
            $js .= $script;
            $js .= '</script>';
            break;

         default:
            $success = FALSE;
            break;
      }

      // Add to js array if it doesn't already exist
      if ($js != NULL && !in_array($js, $this->js))
      {
         $this->js[] = $js;
         $this->write('_scripts', $js);
      }

      return $success;
   }
```

template.php config file

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Template Configuration (adjust this or create your own)
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

$template['default']['template'] = 'templates/default_template';
$template['default']['regions'] = array(
    'header',
    'left',
    'right',
    'footer',
);
$template['default']['parser'] = 'parser';
$template['default']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
$template['default']['parse_template'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Template Configuration (adjust this or create your own)
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$template['single']['template'] = 'templates/single_template';
$template['single']['regions'] = array(
    'header',
    'center',
    'footer',
);
$template['single']['parser'] = 'parser';
$template['single']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
$template['single']['parse_template'] = FALSE;

/* End of file template.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/config/template.php */
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but why not have the header and footer areas defined in your "single" template? One of the reasons I latched onto this library was so I didn't have to add the header and footer views for each controller method. 

Can you post your template library config?

Comment: Actually it never occurred to me but i will do that now.  just old habit i guess.

the template library is autoloaded in the CI autoload config.

keep in mind the above code is not changed with your suggestion yet.  thanks for that.

I have added the template config file above.

Comment: this has something to do with php and short tags.